# How to apply an expression to an IQueryable for Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, expression, iqueryable

I've got a dictionary of lambda expressions:

```
private readonly Dictionary<SortSpec, Func<IQueryable<CompanyData>, IQueryable<CompanyData>>> _sortHelp =
new Dictionary<SortSpec, Func<IQueryable<CompanyData>, IQueryable<CompanyData>>>()
{
    { SortSpec.ByIsSomethingASC, (i => i.OrderBy(j => j.Whatever)) },
    { SortSpec.ByIsSomethingDESC, (i => i.OrderByDescending(j => j.Whatever)) },
    { SortSpec.ByNameDESC, i => i.OrderByDescending(j => j.Name)}
    //...
}
```

Now, I was hoping to be able to

```
IQueryable<CompanyData> withOrder = _sortHelp[sortSpec](querySoFar);
```

and get an IQueryable that will later translate to the correct sql statement.

However, this doesn't work.
I've tried using expressions, but I seem to miss something.
So, how can I apply such a function to an IQueryable?

Comment: you should be storing `Expressions<Func<CompanyData, T>>` and using them to sort your queryable

Comment: That would be a member expression, not a sort expression.

Comment: Can you explain what means it doesn't work? Does it work if you use `OrderBy*` directly to `IQueryable `?

Comment: @Volker yeah you use the member expression to do the sort, store them in a dictionary of Expression<Func<T, Object>> then right before using them in the order by Strip out the implicit Convert to object to restore the original expression

Comment: For the second time, what do you mean by "doesn't work"? Be more specific; as it is your question starts off with "I have this piece of incomplete code which *doesn't work*" (whatever that means)... Not only have you *not* provided an MCVE *or the error messages* (assuming there are any) necessary for us to reproduce your issue, but you've then followed *that* up with an extremely broad question (along the lines of "how can I pass an IQueryable to an anonymous function?") which doesn't seem to follow on from your intention! Can you see why I'm voting to close it?

Comment: "For the second time, what do you mean by "doesn't work"?" Either it doesn't compile or I get a runtime error because EF can't translate a method call to SQL. The code I have shown doesn't compile.